# ¿Qué es una "uterancia"?

Tags: vocabulario, significado

Mi profe que es bilingüe me dijo que existía el concepto de *uterancia* y despertó mi curiosidad.

Según la [definición de Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Utterance):

> *An utterance is the smallest unit of speech. It is a continuous piece of speech beginning and ending with a clear pause. In the case of oral languages, it is generally but not always bounded by silence.*

¿Corresponde en español la misma definición? ¿Se aplica este concepto cuando se trata de explicar la gramática de una afirmación?

Comment: Ya tienes la respuesta de Diego que aclara todo, pero quiero anotar que el término "utterance" es un tecnicismo de la pragmalingüística, y en ese contexto se lo traduce exclusivamente como "uterancia", nunca como "enunciado", para no usar este otro concepto de la lingüística general. O sea, tienes que tener la misma precaución de siempre con el lenguaje técnico, cuyas palabras no siempre aparecen en los diccionarios.

Comment: @Rodrigo precisamente quería saber si había un equivalente porque al menos en la RAE no aparece.

Comment: @Ustanak - ¿Dónde viste la palabra?  ¡Hay que mostrar el contexto!

Comment: @aparente001 no tengo contexto. Solamente la mencioné porque la he leído bastante en algunas cosas de gramática.

Comment: *Cosas de gramática* -- gracias, eso ya es algo...  Y si tienes una frase que contiene el termino....

Comment: @aparente001 date una vuelta por el English Language & Usage. Ahí en el buscador puedes ver la palabra *utterance* y te encontrás con muchas publicaciones en donde se usa.

Comment: Conozco "utterance" y lo uso en inglés, fuera del contexto de la gramática.  Pero nunca habia visto *uterancia*.

Comment: @aparente001 yo tampoco. Por eso quise preguntar si había un equivalente a ello. De hecho mi profe que es bilingüe me dijo que existía el concepto de *uterancia* y despertó mi curiosidad.

Comment: Sospecho que tu profe quiso traer una palabra del ingles al espa~nol.  Eso es muy comun con la gente bilingüe.  ¿Por qué no le preguntas a él cómo él lo aprendió?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ya que aportabas la [definición de wikipedia para utterance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Utterance), hice click en el menú de la izquierda para cambiar el idioma a español y el término es traducido como [enunciado](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enunciado).

> En pragmática, un enunciado es un acto de habla (acto locativo) mínimo, realizado mediante una oración o una expresión sintáctica más pequeña que una oración. Informalmente se usa enunciado como sinónimo de oración, aunque pragmáticamente existen diferencias.

Según el DRAE un `enunciado` es

> **[enunciado](http://dle.rae.es/?id=FqtGFhC)**
>
> 2. m. Secuencia de palabras delimitada por pausas muy marcadas, que puede estar constituida por una o varias oraciones.
> 3. m. Ling. Secuencia con valor comunicativo, sentido completo y entonación propia.

Así que parece bastante cercano a la definición original en inglés: Menor unidad del habla (discurso) delimitada por silencios o pausas.

Google en cambio propone `declaración` y `pronunciación`. La primera puede ser sinónimo, pero entiendo que la definición del DRAE para enunciado, en las acepciones (y connotaciones) segunda y tercera, recoge el significado de `utterance`.

El término `uterancia` (solo para clarificar a terceros) por supuesto no está recogido en el DRAE.